# CSS selector outside the parent container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to apply some CSS to an element in another class when an element with an ID is on mousehover. I don't want to use JS.

Example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="parent_1">parent_1</div>
    <div id="parent_2">parent_2</div>
    <div id="parent_3">parent_3</div>
</div>

<div class="another_parent">
    <div id="another_parent_1">another_parent_1</div>
    <div id="another_parent_2">another_parent_2</div>
    <div id="another_parent_3">another_parent_3</div>
</div>

<style>#parent_3:hover #another_parent_3 {color: red;}</style>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CvT6U/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible. As per CSS3 specs:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

```
E F an F element descendant of an E element 
E > F   an F element child of an E element  
E + F   an F element immediately preceded by an E element
E ~ F   an F element preceded by an E element
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you not use a general sibling selector?

#parent_3:hover ~ #another_parent_3 {color: red;}

http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/#sibling-selectors

Comment: No, because `#another_parent_3` is contained in a separate container than `#parent_3`. That would work if there were no parents though. I suggest you try this out in the JSFiddle in the question.